# why this JRE error happening during maven build

Tags: maven, java-7

Even though I set the JAVA_HOME and PATH to point to the JDK7 directory, Maven takes the `/usr/bin/` as JVM path and It searches for the `tools.jar` file in the JRE and throws the below error.

```
Fatal error compiling

Embedded error: tools.jar not found: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/tools.jar
```

But if i set the /usr/bin/java to point to the JDK directory manually, it works fine. I am puzzled with this behavior. Can someone explain why it is like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Close terminal and reopen it and check whether `$PATH` is Proper.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME -or-
echo $PATH
```

Assuming that you have a linux machine.

1. Take a look on `/usr/bin/java`, this is a symbolic link. Look where is a target of this symbolic link (in my case the target is at this location `/etc/alternatives/java`)
2. `/etc/alternatives/java` is symbolic link too. Create new symbolic link to "proper" JVM (e.g. Sun's JVM)
3. Replace `/etc/alternatives/java` with newly created symbolic link by `/usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/bin/java 2`